# recycleview doesn't work correctly?

Tags: android, list, android-recyclerview, position, adapter

I'm new in android and working with recyclerview now, i want to change recycleview 3rd item color to blue like this :

1. item0(default)
2. item1(default)
3. item2(default)
4. item3(blue)
5. item4(default)

.
.
.
so, i write down below codes but unfortunately when i scroll the list i get this result !!!!

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(vh holder, int position) {
    Contacts example = contacts.get(position);
    holder.first_name.setText(example.name);
    holder.last_name.setText(example.last_name);

    if (position == 3){
        holder.first_name.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

}
```

[many items changed to blue !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFukY.png)

i really confused . thanks for your help .

Comment: post your complete adapter code

Comment: You are not recycling your View. Post the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `RecyclerView`, the views are reused. The view for one item will be used for another item after scrolling. So in this case, the color of multiple views is changed.

The solution would be to change the color to default in the else condition.

```
if (position == 3) {
    holder.first_name.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
} else {
    holder.first_name.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked !! but i don't know exactly what "View" means in android !! can you help me ??

Comment: Glad I could help. Also don't forget to upvote the answer. In android View is the base class of all the UI elements.

Answer (score 0):

---

// adapter.java ===>

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.vh> {

private List<Contacts> contacts;

public Adapter(List<Contacts> contacts) {
    this.contacts = contacts;
}

public class vh extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected TextView first_name;
    protected TextView last_name;
    protected ImageView Image;

    public vh(View v) {
        super(v);
        first_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.first);
        last_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.last);
        Image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }
}

@Override
public Adapter.vh onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Log.d("creat",String.valueOf(viewType));
    Log.d("creat",String.valueOf(parent));
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
    Log.d("View",String.valueOf(v));
    return new vh(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(vh holder, int position) {
    Contacts example = contacts.get(position);
    holder.first_name.setText(example.name);
    holder.last_name.setText(example.last_name);

    if (position == 3){
        holder.first_name.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.d("Item","ItemCount");
    return contacts.size();
}}
```

---

A contact class for data source : Contacts.java ==>

```
public class Contacts {

public String name;
public String last_name;

public Contacts(String name, String last_name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.last_name = last_name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getLast_name() {
    return last_name;
}

public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
    this.last_name = last_name;
}}
```

---

and the main activity : ListActivity.java ==>

```
public class ListActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);


    List<Contacts> l = new ArrayList<>();
    l.add(new Contacts("Alireza","Akbari"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Akbari","Alireza"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Alireza","Akbari"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Akbari","Alireza"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Alireza","Akbari"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Akbari","Alireza"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Alireza","Akbari"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Akbari","Alireza"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Alireza","Akbari"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Akbari","Alireza"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Alireza","Akbari"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Akbari","Alireza"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Alireza","Akbari"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Akbari","Alireza"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Alireza","Akbari"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Akbari","Alireza"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Alireza","Akbari"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Akbari","Alireza"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Alireza","Akbari"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Akbari","Alireza"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Alireza","Akbari"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Akbari","Alireza"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Alireza","Akbari"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Akbari","Alireza"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Alireza","Akbari"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Akbari","Alireza"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Alireza","Akbari"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Akbari","Alireza"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Alireza","Akbari"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Akbari","Alireza"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Alireza","Akbari"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Akbari","Alireza"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Alireza","Akbari"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Akbari","Alireza"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Alireza","Akbari"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Akbari","Alireza"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Alireza","Akbari"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Akbari","Alireza"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Alireza","Akbari"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Akbari","Alireza"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Alireza","Akbari"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Akbari","Alireza"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Alireza","Akbari"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Akbari","Alireza"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Alireza","Akbari"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Akbari","Alireza"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Alireza","Akbari"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Akbari","Alireza"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Alireza","Akbari"));
    l.add(new Contacts("Akbari","Alireza"));




    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    Adapter cAdapter = new Adapter(l);
    rv.setAdapter(cAdapter);
    LinearLayoutManager lm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    lm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    rv.setLayoutManager(lm);

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recyclerview reuse the view..

you can simply fix by adding 'else'

```
if (position == 3){
        holder.first_name.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
}
else{
        holder.first_name.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}
```